# Error in FUN(dd[x, ], ...) : could not find function "FUN" using by()

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `by` function in R with the means function. When I use other functions, such as median and sd it works, but just not with mean.

```
means = by(y, factors, mean)
```

I am getting the error:

> Error in FUN(dd[x, ], ...) : could not find function "FUN"

Comment: You need to delete the `mean` object from your workspace: `rm(mean)`.

Answer (score 3):

You've most likely got junk in your R workspace:

Create some data

```
y <- 1:6
factors <- gl(3,2)
```

Create an object called "mean":

```
mean <- 100
```

Try to run your `by` command:

```
by(y, factors, mean)
#Error in FUN(dd[x, ], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
```

Remove the "mean" object

```
rm(mean)
```

Try again

```
by(y, factors, mean)  # It works!
factors: 1
[1] 1.5
------------------------------------------------------ 
factors: 2
[1] 3.5
------------------------------------------------------ 
factors: 3
[1] 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that I made the following mistake with my join, where I also used "by":

FALSE:   `join(x, y, by = (id, name))`
CORRECT: `join(x, y, by = c(id, name))`